# list comprehension c несколькими списками и условиями

Tags: pandas

Есть дата фрейм

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [10, 150, 9, 13],
                    'R1':[101,102,103,104]})
```

требуется создать новую колонку 'Rnew' на основе имеющихся данных.
условия для заполнения колонки:

```
if Val >100 then Rnew = f(R1)
            else Rnew = R1
f(R1) = min(150; sqrt(100*(Val-100)+R1*R1*2.71)
```

хотелось бы реализовать с помощью спискового включения, и посмотреть скорость выполнения.
сейчас работает через numpy:

```
df['tmp'] = np.sqrt(100*(df['Val']-100) + np.power(df['R1'], 2)*2.71)
df['Rnew'] = np.where(df['Val'] > 100, np.where(df['tmp'] > 150, 150, df['tmp']), df['R1'])
```